# What is JavaScript AST, how to play with it?

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree

Abstract Syntax Tree.. I always heard that compile to SpiderMonkey AST on Github.
So, is that a actual standard of JS syntax tree? And there's V8, is V8 using the same kind of AST?

How can I play with that?

Comment: Here's a handy visualization of javascript AST execution: http://int3.github.io/metajs/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

SpiderMonkey offers the [parser api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API). This is probably the easiest way to get your hands on the syntax objects.

There's also open *js-js* parsers like [Esprima](http://esprima.org/) (which is ECMAScript, really, but it's right up the alley)

Answer (score 71):

1.You can take a look at [AST explorer](https://astexplorer.net/). An online tool to explore the ASTs generated by more than 10 parsers. It is a good tool to learn AST tree of a language.
[AST explorer source at Github.com](https://github.com/fkling/astexplorer).

[image]

---

2.Also you can paste your js code into [JavaScript AST visualizer](http://jointjs.com/demos/javascript-ast) and click "show ast" button, you will see the AST visully.

demo js code:

```
function foo(d) {
  d += 3;
    return d+999
}
function bar(d) {
    return d*100
}
```

[image: js ast demo]

Comment: what is the benefit of this image? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 15):

Abstract Syntax Tree (AST), is a tree representation of program source code.

There is a couple JavaScript `AST` standards:

- [estree](https://github.com/estree/estree) - standard for EcmaScript AST;
- [shift](https://shift-ast.org/) - was designed with transformation in mind, [not compatible with estree](https://blog.shapesecurity.com/2015/01/06/a-technical-comparison-of-the-shift-and-spidermonkey-ast-formats/);
- [babel](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/main/packages/babel-parser/ast/spec.md) - supports language features which is have not yet become a standard, but have a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals).

Here is a list of JavaScript parsers:

- [esprima](https://esprima.org) one of the first
- [acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn) very popular, fast and stable
- [espree](https://github.com/eslint/espree) based on `acorn`, used in [eslint](https://eslint.org);
- [@babel/parser](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-parser) based on `acorn`, supports all new language features
- [shfit-ast parser](https://shift-ast.org/parser.html) produces `Shift AST`
- [typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) can parse JavaScript and TypeScript, producing it's own AST format for this

You can find more parsers on [astexplorer.net](https://astexplorer.net/), most of them `estree` compatible.

While most parsers that supports `estree` can be easily replaced by each other, `babel` has very rich infrastructure needed to comfortable work with `AST`.
It has:

- [handbook](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md) describing all the tools, and ways to use it.
- [@babel/traverse](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-traverse.html) -  maintains the overall tree state, and is responsible for replacing, removing, and adding nodes;
- [@babel/template](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-template) - simplest way to create a `AST`-node from string.
- [@babel/types](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-types) - contains builders and checkers of `AST`-nodes.

One of the simplest way to play with `AST`, is using [putout](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout), which is based on `babel` and supports simplified way of transforming `JavaScript` code with help of [plugins API](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout#plugins-api).

Here is example of removing `DebuggerStatement` node:

```js
module.exports.replace = () => ({
    'debugger': '',
});
```

If you want switch places of variables, changing the way of declaration:

```js
module.exports.replace = () => ({
    'let __a = __b': 'const __b = __a'
});
```

If you want transform this code into `return x[0]`:

```js
for (const x of y) {
    return x;
}
```

You can use:

```js
module.exports.replace = () => ({
    'for (const __a of __b) {return __a}': 'return __a[0]',
});
```

With help of `putout` you can make simplest transformation of `JavaScript` code without handling with `AST` directly.

Comment: i have raised an issue with the nodejs team for a status follow up with tc9 proposal. pls vote and support his feature status request in the github issue i raised if you think this should be a feature in the nodejs. the feature is available in python. https://www.github.com/nodejs/node/issues/45158

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to try out the acron parser from professor Marijnh
https://github.com/marijnh try out this link: https://astexplorer.net/

This is a tiny, fast JavaScript parser, written completely in JavaScript.

The above-mentioned [JavaScript AST visualizer](http://jointjs.com/demos/javascript-ast) uses Esprima engine and has been also written in JavaScrpt.

JavaScript dominates in parsing AST because JavaScript engines are super optimized today. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine

> SpiderMonkey AST standard of JS syntax tree? Is V8 using the same kind of AST?

Both of these web browser engines do have AST processing inside written in C++. This is why JavaScrpt code will run fast in most cases except for `eval`.

Comment: the video link is invalid

Comment: Thanks @JuanPicado, I removed the link.

Answer (score 1):

I know only of one specification of Javascript AST: https://github.com/estree/estree

It originated from publication of Dave Herman from Mozilla and since then evolved as community standard. So it should match SpiderMonkey at some degree but I'm not sure about V8 and JSC.

Would appreciate if someone could provide more information on the matter.