# ternJS - Generate JSON type definition file

Tags: javascript, json, tern

[ternJS](http://ternjs.net/) have several. JSON files [defs](https://github.com/marijnh/tern/tree/master/defs) which contains the definition of librarys. Can someone explain to me how I can best generate my own to my javascript libraries / or only definition  objects?

I can not see that there is no common procedure for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a tool for this included in Tern. See `condense` at http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#utils . It runs Tern on your file and tries to output the types that it finds. It's far from flawless, but for simple programs it works well. For files with a complicated structure or interface, you'll often have to hand-write the definitions.

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways I have thought about to solve your problem:

### **Using Abstract Syntax Tree Parser and Visitor**

One way to solve your problem would be to use **abstract syntax tree parser** and **visitor** in order to automate the task of scanning through the code and documenting it.

The resources here will be of help:

-http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/understanding-ast-created-by-mozilla-rhino-parser/
 -[What is JavaScript AST, how to play with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127985/what-is-javascript-ast-how-to-play-)

You usually use a parser to retrieve a tree, and then use a visitor to visit all the nodes and do your work within there.

You will essentially have a tree representing the specific library and then you must write the code to store this in the def format you link to.

### Getting a Documentation Generator and Modifying

Another idea is to download the source code for a documentation generator, e.g. https://github.com/yui/yuidoc/

By modifying the styling/output format you can generate "documentation" in the appropriate json format.

### Converting Existing Documentation (HTML doc) into JSON

You can make a parser that takes a standard documentation format (I'm sure as Javadoc is one for java there should be one for javascript), and write a converter that exctracts the relevant information and stores in a JSON definition.

Comment: I counted at least that they had not written defs manually xD hehe

Comment: Maybe ask them? :) ... I noticed they also include URLs to documentation within the defs which points also that they scrapped/crawled or manually entered data. I also suspect if they maybe generated the defs from crawling through the docs. I've updated my answer with 2 more options.

Comment: Thx, Learned a lot from this here :)! Thank you. +1. But I think doing it the way it is supposed from tern :)