# How to parse GraphQL request string into an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am running Apollo lambda server for GraphQL. I want to intercept the GraphQL query/mutation from the POST request body and parse it so I can find out which query/mutation the request is asking for. The environment is Node.js.

The request isn't JSON, it's GraphQL query language. I've looked around to try and find a way to parse this into an object that I can navigate but I'm drawing a blank.

The Apollo server must be parsing it somehow to direct the request. Does anyone know a library that will do this or pointers on how I can parse the request? Examples of request bodies and what I want to retrieve below.

```
{"query":"{\n  qQueryEndpoint {\n    id\n  }\n}","variables":null,"operationName":null}
```

I would like to identify that this is a query and that `qQueryEndpoint` is being asked for.

```
{"query":"mutation {\\n  saveSomething {\\n    id\\n  }\\n}","variables":null}
```

I would like to identify that this is a mutation and the `saveSomething` mutation is being used.

My first idea for this is to strip out the line breaks and try and use regular expressions to parse the request but it feels like a very brittle solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is JavaScript AST, how to play with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127985/what-is-javascript-ast-how-to-play-with-it)

Comment: My question was wrong. The request is GraphQL query language, not AST. I have edited. Thank you for your input!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-parser ?

Comment: @GabrielBleu from what I understand of the docs, that package generates queries from objects not object from queries.

Comment: It parses the query string and returns an object, but https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-tag seems way more popular.

Comment: @GabrielBleu From the docs of that package: 'That's where this package comes in - it lets you write your queries with ES2015 template literals and compile them into an AST with the gql tag.'

I can't find which functionality gets me an object, am I missing something?

Comment: I was thinking something like : `const query = gql\`${body.query}\``

Comment: @GabrielBleu ahhhh ok, I'll go give it a spin locally and report back!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [graphql-tag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-tag) :

```
const gql = require('graphql-tag');

const query = `
  {
    qQueryEndpoint {
      id
    }
  }
`;

const obj = gql`
  ${query}
`;

console.log('operation', obj.definitions[0].operation);
console.log('name', obj.definitions[0].selectionSet.selections[0].name.value);
```

Prints out :

```
operation query
name qQueryEndpoint
```

And with your mutation :

```
operation mutation
name saveSomething
```

Comment: Do we have someting similar for golang ?

Answer (score 29):

`graphql-tag` is built upon the core `graphql` library (and thus installs it along) - if you just want to get the type of operation and the name of it you can do so, by using `graphql` directly and analyze the full AST of the parsed GraphQL operation:

```js
const { parse } = require('graphql');

const query = `
{
  qQueryEndpoint {
    id
  }
} 
`;

const mutation = `
mutation {
  saveSomething {
    id
  }
}
`;
const firstOperationDefinition = (ast) => ast.definitions[0];
const firstFieldValueNameFromOperation = (operationDefinition) =>  operationDefinition.selectionSet.selections[0].name.value;

const parsedQuery = parse(query);
const parsedMutation = parse(mutation);

console.log('operation', firstOperationDefinition(parsedQuery).operation);
console.log('firstFieldName', firstFieldValueNameFromOperation(firstOperationDefinition(parsedQuery)));

console.log('operation', firstOperationDefinition(parsedMutation).operation);
console.log('firstFieldName', firstFieldValueNameFromOperation(firstOperationDefinition(parsedMutation)));
```

That way you do not need to depend on `graphql-tag` and you can use, the *real* GraphQL AST (and thus easily adapt to further requirements) - because `graphql-tag` does not provide the full AST.

See the AST for the query in [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/79a260c7422cc5abac3d4f90302873be/f2f8980f71e8e17351eaf0fffa45f8e5108e65e3).

Answer (score 3):

You could use `graphql-js` like so:

```js
const { parse, visit } = require('graphql');

const query = `
  {
    books {
      ...rest of the query
    }
  }
`

const ast = parse(query);

const newAst = visit(ast, {
  enter(node, key, parent, path, ancestors) {
    // do some work
  },
  leave(node, key, parent, path, ancestors) {
    // do some more work
  }
});
```

I belive this is what graphql server implementations uses under the hood, I could be mistaken though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `graphql-tag`.

```
const gql = require('graphql-tag');

const query = `
  {
    qQueryEndpoint {
      id
    }
  }
`;

const obj = gql`
  ${query}
`;

console.log('operation', obj.definitions[0].operation);
console.log('operationName', obj.definitions[0].name.value);
```