# Parse gql query string to DocumentNode object

Tags: graphql, cypress

I am using `graphql-requst` node module.
My problem is how can I get the operationName from the gql query string.
I referenced this question, but I can't get the query's DocumentNode object.
I think I can get the operationName after parse the gql string to the DocumentNode object.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the DocumentNode object with the `graphql-request` module. Please use `graphql-tag` instead of `graphql-request`.

Please reference my answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047259/how-to-parse-graphql-request-string-into-an-object/73733746#73733746).