# Check data type from string input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-structures

I'm trying to get the DataType(?) from string input value.

```
const data = ['1', 'hello', '[]', '{key: [value]}', '`2020-10-08`'];

function funct(data: string): DataType {
    if(??) {
        return Object
    } else if(??) {
        return Number
    } else if(??) {
        return Array
    } else if (??) {
        return Date
    }
    return String
}

data.map((d) => console.log(funct(data)));
// Number, String, Array, Object, Data
```

---

```
function funct(d) {
    if(d.startsWith('{') && d.endsWith('}')) {
        return typeof {}
    } else if(d.indexOf('-') !== -1 && !isNaN(Date.parse(d))) {
        return 'Date';
    } else if(!isNaN(parseFloat(d))) {
        return typeof 1
    } else if(d.startsWith('[') && d.endsWith(']')) {
        return typeof []
    } else return typeof 'string'
}
console.log('number', funct('1'));
console.log('number', funct('123'));
console.log('string', funct('`as2d`'));
console.log('string', funct('2s2d'));
console.log('Object', funct('{}'));
console.log('Array', funct('[]')); //object :( 
console.log('Array', funct('["d", "f"]')); //object :(
```

Comment: this might be too hard

Comment: You've to create your own JS parser, if you can't use the built-in parser (`eval`), which very often is not a safe solution.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call(eval('1'))` ...

Comment: uhm I think I need to create my own JS parser... Could you help me with that?

Comment: Actually, you need to have valid JS, ex. `'hello'` can't be parsed to any type, rather it represents a variable name. Loop all strings character by character, test and catecorize, JSON.parse is also helpful for quick evaluation of some types.

Comment: I need an example with a complete code :( Not working on my end

Comment: 'hello' is string type right? :(

Comment: Nope, when stripping the outer quotes, the value to parse is `hello`, a string would be `'"hello"'. "_with a complete code_", you're asking a lot , see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127985/what-is-javascript-ast-how-to-play-with-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
function funct(d) {
    
    if(d.startsWith('{') && d.endsWith('}')) {
        return Object
    } else if(d.indexOf('-') !== -1 && !isNaN(Date.parse(d))) {
        return Date;
    } else if(!isNaN(parseFloat(d))) {
        return Number
    } else if(d.startsWith('[') && d.endsWith(']')) {
        return Array
    } else return String
}
```

Note: this was tested in JS so, I removed the type annotations. Please them if you want to compile it in TypeScript.

Comment: This is what I've been looking for!

Comment: I just edited my question. COuld you check my test cases? It's failing :(

Comment: number function Number() { [native code] }
number function Number() { [native code] }
string function String() { [native code] }
string function Number() { [native code] }
Object function Object() { [native code] }
Array function Array() { [native code] }
Array function Array() { [native code] }

This is the output when I ran your code. Looks okay to me

Comment: For array, don't return typeof value. Array is an object in JavaScript